# Create .pyi file automatically from cython source?

Tags: python, cython, typing

How can I create `.pyi` files from cython source code (`.pyx`)?

Comment: I think there's been a few ([1](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3150) [2](https://github.com/antocuni/capnpy/issues/41) [3](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1826)) people asking for this over the last few years, but nobody's actually done it yet... It's possible that someone may have a better answer, but I think the current status is "no, but it would probably be possible to integrate this with Cython if someone wants to write the code"

Comment: This project does it:
https://pypi.org/project/cythonbuilder/

Comment: @IyadAhmed I think cythonbuilder generates HTML files, doesn't it?

Comment: I tried it and it generated .pyi files ^^, maybe it had an option for HTML but didn't @Winand encounter it ^^

Comment: @IyadAhmed you are right. `cybuilder build` command generates pyi by default. Maybe you can write an answer to this unanswered question?:)

Comment: Ok will try to do

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cythonbuilder package for that,
https://pypi.org/project/cythonbuilder/

1. Install cythonbuilder: `pip install cythonbuilder`
2. Use the command `cythonbuilder.exe build -y` to automatically build all .pyx file in current working directory and generate .pyi files.

[image: Example cythnobuilder project]

Comment: CythonBuilder did not fit naturally into my setup.py files.  
It needed some modification to support some cython types.  

All the parsing code is located in: https://github.com/mikehuls/cythonbuilder/blob/main/cythonbuilder/pyigenerator.py  
It does not support all cython syntax but it was workable with a few updates.

Eventually, I created my own parser with pyparsing.  It is a bit overkill for creating stub files but allows for modifications. It supported most of cython stub related syntax. 

https://github.com/RaubCamaioni/CythonPEG/blob/main/cython_peg.py

Comment: Amazing work! ~~filler text to post comment~~